# Value with parametrized validation with ES6 class inheriance

Tags: javascript, validation, oop, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I'm rewriting some old Chrome extension code while simultaneously trying to learn new ES6 tricks, and I'm running into some design questions.

My goal is to provide a value storage (which is backed by the asynchronous `chrome.storage` for persistence, but that's outside the scope of the question). What I want is to associate some validation with the values. So, my `Storage` is a collection of `Values`, each associated with a validation function.

In my old version, I would just pass a validation function when I instantiate a value, something like this (simplified):

```
Storage["key1"] = new Value({
  validator: ValidatorIsInteger, defaultValue: 0, /* ... */
});
Storage["key2"] = new Value({
  validator: ValidatorEnum(["a", "b", "c"]), defaultValue: "a", /* ... */
});
```

However, I'm trying to rewrite this with `Value` being a `class` that can be extended with specific validators, which seemed to be a good idea at the time. Again, simplified:

```
class Value {
  constructor(key, defaultValue) {
    this.key = key;
    this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    this.set(defaultValue);
  }

  set(newValue) {
    var validationResult = this.validate(newValue);
    if (validationResult.pass) {
      this.value = newValue;
      return newValue;
    } else {
      throw new RangeError(
        `Value ${newValue} for ${this.key} failed validation: ${validationResult.message}`
      );
    }
  }

  get() { return this.value; }

  // Overload in children
  validate(value) {
    return {pass: true};
  }
}

class IntegerValue extends Value {
  validate(value) {
    if (Number.isInteger(value)) {
      return {pass: true};
    } else {
      return {pass: false, message: "Value must be an integer"};
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good. However, I run into [problems](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/ch3.md#subclass-constructor) when trying to make a parametrized child class:

```
class EnumValue extends Value {
  constructor(key, defaultValue, possibleValues) {
    this.possibleValues = possibleValues; // NUH-UH, can't set that before super()
    super(key, defaultValue);
  }

  // Will be called from parent constructor
  validate(value) {
    if (this.possibleValues.includes(value)) {
      return {pass: true};
    } else {
      return {pass: false, message: `Value must be in [${this.possibleValues}]`};
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is in "setting up" the parametrized validator before `.set(defaultValue)` is called. I see several ways out of this, all of which seems lacking:

- Resign, and not use the `class`-extension-based approach - *I want to see if it can be fixed first*.
- Always trust the default value as a workaround to calling `.set(defaultValue)` - *bad, because I don't want accidentally inconsistent data*.
- Make `.set()` asynchronous, giving the constructor a chance to finish before validation is performed - *while the persistence backend is asynchronous, the purpose of `Storage` is, among other things, to provide a synchronous "cache"*.

Am I failing to see some obvious fix to this approach? If not, and this is simply a wrong tool for the job, how should I re-organize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic problem with calling overrideable methods (`validate`, via `set`) from constructors; [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors) (different language, same problem).

Your *specific* example lends itself to a couple of workarounds, but the *general* issue remains.

To solve the general problem, I'd set `value` directly, not via `set`, and use unit tests to ensure that I didn't create validators that have an invalid default value. That is, after all, a coding error, not a runtime error.

But if you want to keep calling `set`, a couple of options:

- You could have the concept of a `Value` that **has** no default value, which might be useful in general anyway. That would solve the problem by letting you have a `Value` constructor that doesn't expect to receive a default value. You could give a `Value` a default value after construction via `setDefaultValue` or similar; that method would validate, but that's fine, because it would be called post-construction in the subclass.
- You could give `Value` a "validating" and "non-validating" state, and have the constructor accept a flag for which state it should start out in. Subclasses would use `false` if they had special validation behavior, ensure that all their ducks are in a row, and then set the validation state (which would validate).

Comment: Thank you for the "classic problem" link, I have little OOP experience so explanation of standard gotchas is very helpful.